# Run docker but get This site can’t be reached 192.168.99.100 refused to connect

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I unable to access docker exposed port on windows machine. In details I do the following:

```
$ docker build -t abc01 .
$ docker run -d -p 80:4000 abc01
```

Then I try to reach docker container in browser:

```
http://192.168.99.100:4000
```

and get annoying result:

```
This site can’t be reached 192.168.99.100 refused to connect.
```

What is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You are exposing the right ports, however, you need to access the website at: 80 instead of 4000, given that 4000 is the port on which your application is listening.

The way exposing ports in Docker works is as follows:

```
docker run -p 80:4000 myImage
```

*where*

```
80[is the outside port]
```

The one is exposed on your host and you will use it in your browser

```
4000 [is the inside port]
```

The port that is used inside the container by the application